# lldb read memory pointer

Tags: memory, reverse-engineering, lldb

It is possible to easily read a memory at a location pointed to by a another address.

For example, $r0 = 0x15942600 at this memory address there is AC B8 EC 14

Now to read the memory at 0x14ecb8ac, I will have to do:

```
mem read $r0
mem read 0x14ecb8ac
```

Any way to easily do a `mem read ($r0)` such that I can read the memory easily?

I have tried this:

```
(lldb) mem re $r1
0x007db594: 7c d5 e7 15 00 00 00 00 e4 b5 7d 00 70 f6 9a 36

(lldb) mem read 0x15e7d57c
0x15e7d57c: 74 69 63 72 63 74 37 35 00 00 63 61 00 00 49 39

(lldb) mem read '*(char **)$r1'
error: invalid start address expression.
error: address expression "*(char **)$r1" evaluation failed
```

Comment: I don't have an architecture with an r0 register to test this, but `mem read  '*(char **)$r0'` ought to work.

Comment: Hey @MarkPlotnick I've tried it, doesn't work.

Comment: Interesting. What architecture is the target, and what version of lldb?

Comment: Does `p *(int **)$r1` give an error?

Comment: Hmm. So *(char **) gives an error but *(int **) works?

Comment: yep. Oh yea, target arch is ARM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @MarkPlotnick this works,

```
mem read '*(int **)$r1'
```

If you need to read a mem address at a certain offset, the following can be done,

```
mem read '*(int **)($r1+4)'
```

Tried and tested against Xcode debugging against ARMv7 and ARM64

Comment: Isn't it more correct to write `mem read '*(int*)$r1'`? In this case, you read the memory of the address given by dereferencing `$r1`.